# Application Insights for Java: how to create a child unit of work

Tags: java, azure-application-insights

Out of the box AI works very well when it comes to correlate the web requests and its dependencies, events etc.
But assuming I have a long running background job, I would like to split its tracking into smaller pieces, units of work or spans, all within the same parent (and this division could go further too). Just like [that image](https://miro.medium.com/max/1080/1*Yu0bCux_sulHPy6MhT9Ytg.png)
Can I somehow do it in code?

Answer (score 0):

A new SDK called `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService` was released very recently which is best suited for these type of background jobs, and non-HTTP workloads like messaging, console applications etc. [This](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-monitor-adds-worker-service-sdk-new-asp-net-core-metrics/) is the blog announcing the Worker service SDK, with detailed instructions on onboarding different types of supported scenarios with examples [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service).

However, while this is a .Net core solution, I can check with our internal Teams about the available options for Java applications and get back as I have more information. To pursue this further, please help me with the following additional details about your app environment from your end:

- What Azure services do you use in this application's ecosystem? (VMs / DBs / App Services?)
- What is the framework used in code?
- Are there any Load Balancers or PaaS services also involved? If yes, how is their performance measured? Where are their logs configured?

This information would certainly help us understand your setup better. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. We use dockerized Spring-Boot apps, that depend on Azure MSSQL. But basically the infrastructure setup doesn't play a role in this question - my app might just have a thread that every 10 minutes performs some business operation and I would assign to it separate operationId...